# How to change "permalink" structure in "Wordpress Thesis" theme?

Tags: permalinks, theme-thesis

I have installed Thesis theme. The default permalink structure is 
`BLOGURL/%postid%/`

When I change it to `BLOGURL/%postname%/`, I can't access the pages.

I have modified `.htaccess` file and the "nav_bar function" as well.

Can somebody help me out? I can't figure out the redirection error.

Comment: Perhaps posting the contents of your .htaccess would folks troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Jagira - Changing permalinks in Thesis is pretty straightforward.  What made you think to change htaccess and the nav_bar function?

Answer (score 2):

first set it to default url & see  whether eveything is right, then delete all text in .htaccess   & add the new url format you need & save & get .htaccess updated & see your site

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using .htaccess but I would take a look at WP Rewrite Class , it may also be what you're looking for for this kind of thing.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

> > As the rewrite rules are a crucial part of your weblog functionality, WordPress allows plugins to hook into the generation
> >     process at several points. rewrite_rules(), specifically, contains
> >     nine filters and one hook for really precise control over the rewrite
> >     rules process. Here's what you can filter in rewrite_rules(): To
> >     filter the rewrite rules generated for permalink URLs, use
> >     post_rewrite_rules. To filter the rewrite rules generated for dated
> >     archive URLs, use date_rewrite_rules. To filter the rewrite rules
> >     generated for category archive URLs, use category_rewrite_rules. To
> >     filter the rewrite rules generated for search URLs, use
> >     search_rewrite_rules. To filter the rewrite rules generated for the
> >     latest comment feed URLs, use comments_rewrite_rules. To filter the
> >     rewrite rules generated for author archive URLs, use
> >     author_rewrite_rules. To filter the rewrite rules generated for your
> >     Pages, use page_rewrite_rules. To filter the rewrite rules generated
> >     for the root of your weblog, use root_rewrite_rules. To filter the
> >     whole lot, use rewrite_rules_array. The action hook
> >     generate_rewrite_rules runs after all the rules have been created. If
> >     your function takes a parameter, it will be passed a reference to the
> >     entire $wp_rewrite object.

Hope this helps..

EDIT: Added this link in here as it may help you out as well with what you're trying to accomplish. http://www.dev4press.com/2012/tutorials/wordpress/practical/how-wordpress-url-rewriting-works/

Comment: Thanks for the late answer to a two year old question. +1